# Twenty Seventeen theme: custom left part under the page title

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

I'm using the Twenty Seventeen theme and would like to add an image and some links to the left part under the page title. I searched all over the web, but couldn't find a good solution.  Is there any way to accomplish that without creating a custom static page?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, was my question not clear?

Comment: Hi. You didn't mention what are the image and the link about. Some manual link? featured image? Ads?

Comment: Is this for pages only? Only the front page? There are many template files to edit, so please be a little more specific about where you need to make edits and what you've already tried.

Comment: @Jack Johansson. Manual link. Any image from the Media Library.

Comment: @Spartacus. This should hopefully work on any page.

Comment: @user1566515 there are a lot of answers but no up/down votes or comment replies explaining why they don't answer the question, as well as some other details missing, e.g. is the image and text the same everywhere, or on a per post basis? Do you have the image and text already stored in post meta?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Currently there are 3 answers and I upvoted 2 of them and asked some follow-up questions. As far as the third answer, I'm not qualified to judge if it's a valid solution as I'm not an expert in client-side scripting and just prefer to avoid it. Image and text can be the same or different, but that's trivial to set up. I would prefer using image and text already in post meta, but could just enter them in HTML. My main problem was locating the relevant php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any specific function to hook to, so a back-end solution would require altering the "/template-parts/page/content-page.php template file (via a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), preferably), namely adding your desired elements right before the closing `</header>` tag, for example:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <?php twentyseventeen_edit_link( get_the_ID() ); ?>
    <!-- START new code -->
    <img src="http://image-source.jpg">
    <span class="left-text">Insert your text here</span>
    <!-- END new code -->
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

You can also add conditional statements if you wish the new content to be displayed on a specific page/pages, e.g. for a front page:

```
<!-- START new code -->
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <img src="http://image-source.jpg">
    <span class="left-text">Insert your text here</span>
<?php } ?>
<!-- END new code -->
```

for a specific page ID:

```
<!-- START new code -->
<?php if ( 25 == get_the_ID() ) { ?>
    <img src="http://image-source.jpg">
    <span class="left-text">Insert your text here</span>
<?php } ?>
<!-- END new code -->
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually already using a child theme. 1) Is there a way to edit content-page.php via WP admin interface? If not, is it possible to edit additional content via WP admin, just like regular page text? 2) If I add content-page.php to the child theme, will the parent's content-page.php be completely ignored?

Comment: @user1566515 to answer your questions, 1) not in the core - you'll need a plugin for that, e.g. the [WPide](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpide/) 2) yes, [it will](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files); the only file that doesn't get overridden by a child theme if included is the parent's functions.php

Answer (score 1):

If it is related to `the_title`, you can use filter [`the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/), but base on twenty seventeen theme code for page template, your custom code will be markup inside `h1` element [`the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/1.3/template-parts/page/content-page.php#L17)

For example code, just say we need to add only in page with the post id = 2

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $id ) {
    static $i;

    //add conditional page and in loop, i.e post id = 2
    if ( is_page( 2 ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $i++;

        //add conditional for filter position
        if ( 1 === $i ) {

            //add your code here
            $title .= '<p><img src="image.jpg"></p>';
            $title .= '<p>' . __( 'Text', 'textdomain' ) . '</p>';
            $title .= '<p><a href="#link">' . __( 'Link' ) . '</a></p>';
        }
    }

    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Just change the conditional statement to make it work in another posts or pages.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantage to using this approach over what Andrii Shekhirev suggested?

Comment: I don't say this is as advantage, but with this approach, you don't have to create new file and code in it under your child theme, so you only use it inside `functions.php` child theme.

Comment: Thanks again! I will go with Andrii Shekhirev's answer, but I wish I could divide the bounty between your two answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the most obvious way is javascript which will be used after the page loaded. By the way WP has included jQuery, so you can:

1. create styles to achieve a clear two columns design (or use already existing ones if you are using bootstrap-like stylesheets, I'll assume forward that your WP uses it)
2. find the block of html you want to shift left and assign `.column` class to it.
3. It's possible that you will have to wrap both of you columns into a block similar to one with a bootstrap class `.row`.
4. Create with jQuery a new element with your image and other content that should be displayed.
5. Insert the element from the point 3 to the DOM (existing HTML structure of your page) right after opened block `.row` from the point 2.

That's it.
Feel free to ask details on topic.